# Pandas comparing columns to specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I've created a dataframe filled with strings.'Date' values are unique, other columns have repeating content

```
d = {'Date':['1','2','3','4','5'],
     'col1':['a','a','b','b','b','e'],
     'col2':['c','c','c','c','d','f']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
    Day  col1  col2
0     1     a     c
1     2     a     c
2     3     b     c
3     4     b     c
4     5     b     d
5     6     e     f
```

I want to choose one row and tests how many it's values repeat in all the remaining rows. The only logic tests I came up with always returns False.

```
chosen = df.loc[df['Date'] == '3']
print(chosen)
      Day   col1  col2
2     3     b     c

df['Result'] = 0
for i in chosen.columns[1:]:
    print(i)
    df['Result'] += np.where(df[i].equals(chosen[i]),1,0)
print(df)
    Day  col1  col2   Result
0     1     a     c     0
1     2     a     c     0
2     3     b     c     0
3     4     b     c     0
4     5     b     d     0
5     6     e     f     0
```

Expected output:

```
     Day  col1  col2   Result
0     1     a     c     1
1     2     a     c     1
2     3     b     c     2
3     4     b     c     1
4     5     b     d     1
5     6     e     f     0
```

What is the best way of achieving this? I could create columns with only 'chosen' values and then compare column by column, but I guess this approach would be slow with dozens of columns and thousands of rows.

Comment: Could you please post the expected output for this example?

Comment: I've added it now

Comment: Why is the last number for `a` and `b` "1" instead of being "0" if there are no `a` or `b`s afterwards?

Comment: The 'chosen' row has values col1 = b  col2 = c. I want to know for each row how many of these values repeat. First row has only one repeat (col2 = c), so Result = 1. Last row has both values different, therefore Result = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You only need this line:

```
chosen = len(df.loc[df['Date'] == '3'])
```

Comment: Hi, I've added the expected output. How should I iplement it to get the expected output? Thanks